# Selecting elements from "div" dropdown - Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a "div" dropdown, not "select". So my function works fine everywhere except dropdows which open not from the dropdown button place, but from above (because dropdown is placed at the bottom of the page) to prevent... page scrolling i guess? Maybe the problem is that it opens too fast or too slow or what, so function usually clicks not the needed element but one of the closest to it. Mostly it works this way if element is not at the beginning of dropdown so it is scrolled to the element. Any suggestions what can be made?

The best way i found is to use actions, splitting moving to element and clicking into 2 rows (works much worse if writing in 1 row). By the way, "waitVisibilityOfElement(By)" is a function with webdriver wait for expected conditions

```
public void selectFromDropdown(By by) {
        Log.debug("selecting from dropdown by" + by);
        waitVisibilityOfElement(by);
        Actions actions = new Actions(wrappedWebDriver);
       actions.moveToElement(wrappedWebDriver.findElement(by)).perform();
        Log.debug("clicking dropdown item");
        wrappedWebDriver.findElement(by).click();
}
```

I expect needed element to be clicked, But usually it clicks another one

Ok with some help i came to a final decision which is the best way to select dropdown filters without using any .sleep() functions if other simple ways do not work for you.

```
public void selectFromDropdown(By by) {
        Log.debug("selecting from dropdown by" + by);
        WebElement eleV = wrappedWebDriver.findElement(by);

        waitVisibilityOfElement(by);

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) wrappedWebDriver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", eleV);

        Actions actions = new Actions(wrappedWebDriver);
        actions.moveToElement(wrappedWebDriver.findElement(by)).perform();
        Log.debug("clicking dropdown item");
        wrappedWebDriver.findElement(by).click();
    }
```

Comment: welcome to SO !! How people will know that how the dropdown HTML structure looks like, please read [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add fluet wait before clicking? 
That can be helpful.
Also would be great if you can share information about DOM in that question? 
That is a sample for java, but I think that can help you in js too.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

Comment: Actually I am using java. There is no "nosuchelement" exception thrown, just i guess clicker works faster than menu opens (open animation). It would be hard to give dom code because it is automatically generated by js. Just a lot od divs\spans =)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to scroll to the expected element value before move mouse on it and click. Hope following code can help:

```
public void selectFromDropdown(By by) {
    Log.debug("selecting from dropdown by" + by);
    var eleValue = wrappedWebDriver.findElement(by);
    Log.debug("Scroll to element");
    browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", eleValue);
    waitVisibilityOfElement(by);
    Actions actions = new Actions(wrappedWebDriver);
    actions.moveToElement(eleValue).perform();
    Log.debug("clicking dropdown item");
    eleValue.click();
}
```

Comment: I'm using java so "var" and "browser" what are they? Do I need to add js executor here?

Comment: ok you answer helped me, but I had to modify it myself, I am going to post it into the header

Comment: Yah @VACUUM, I am glad to here that from you :)

Answer (score -1):

If the you are trying to click a static value, you can directly click the value from the dropdown

you can try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("THE VALUE FROM DROPDOWN")).click();
```

Comment: As you can see, this row is used at the end of my function. I'm also selecting by the value. The problem is that usually another element of the menu is selected which is placed close to required one. I guess it happens because selenium clicks faster then menu open animation works

Comment: Possibly. You can try to add a thread.sleep() just to make sure that its not the speed of the web to load that is causing the problem.

Comment: That is Great !